# Re-arrange Text Input fields based on Number entered by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have few inputs, and it comes with values from 1 to 100 in it, but user can alter those values. I have sorted my inputs in Ascending order. Now I want that each time user changes an input, they should be re-arranged in ascending order.
Here is my HTML template:

```js
 var sortedArray = $("div[class^='wrap_']").get().sort(function(a, b) {
   var idx = parseInt($(a).find(".sort_by").val(),10);
   var idx2 = parseInt($(b).find(".sort_by").val(),10);
   return idx > idx2;
});
$(sortedArray).appendTo("body");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap_0">
<input class="sort_by" value="10"/>
</div>
<div class="wrap_1">
    <input class="sort_by" value="3"/>
</div>
<div class="wrap_2">
    <input class="sort_by" value="7"/>
</div>
```

Right now they appear as:
3
7
10
if user changes 3 to 12, I want my output to be automatically changed to:
7 10 12.
    I want Jquery solutions only. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you already have all you need...just add a change event handler and you are good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  sort();
  $(".sort_by").change(function(){
    sort();
  });
  function sort(){
    var sortedArray = $("div[class^='wrap_']").get().sort(function(a, b) {
   var idx = parseInt($(a).find(".sort_by").val(),10);
   var idx2 = parseInt($(b).find(".sort_by").val(),10);
   return idx > idx2;
});
  console.log(sortedArray);
$(sortedArray).appendTo("body");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap_0">
    <input class="sort_by" value="10"/>
</div>
<div class="wrap_1">
    <input class="sort_by" value="3"/>
</div>
<div class="wrap_2">
    <input class="sort_by" value="7"/>
</div>
```

There...you change a value and press enter...your sort code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `input` event and apply the `sort` method on the parent `div` jQuery collection. Please note that I added class `wrap` so the divs can be easily selected. The code `.trigger('input')` ensures that the `input` (actually parent `div`) elements are sorted when the page loads.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.sort_by').on('focusout', function() {
        var arr = $('div.wrap');
        arr = arr.sort(function(a,b) {
            return +$(a).find('.sort_by').val() - +$(b).find('.sort_by').val();
        });
        $('body').append( arr );
    })
    .trigger('focusout');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap_0 wrap">
    <input class="sort_by" value="10"/>
</div>
<div class="wrap_1 wrap">
    <input class="sort_by" value="3"/>
</div>
<div class="wrap_2 wrap">
    <input class="sort_by" value="7"/>
</div>
```

Comment: not to be nitpicking...but a downside of this code is that according to the OP's case if there were a 100 divs and the user were changing the value of a div from '1' to '100'...he would have to give two separate inputs...first 1 to 10 and then 10 to 100

Comment: Good point. All he has to do is replace input with blur or focusout.